# How to monitor (or watch) the data (or schema) changes in a SQL Server database and how to get notified in the client side?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, events, push-notification, signalr

I wanted to use push notification from the SQL Server database side whenever the data (or schema) gets modified. I wanted to implement this in a n-layered service oriented architecture in Asp.Net.

I found `SqlDependency` which was not so helpful due to its limitations in queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using `SqlDependancy` for maintaining in memory cache and it works like magic.

If the query restriction is bothering you, a way around is to add an update/insert trigger on the table you want to monitor for changes. This trigger can write to another simpler table with one field, one row, e.g. **toggles** the `DataChange [BIT]`. (This is just a suggestion, obviously you may want to have the trigger do some other basic operation)

Now with that in place you can use SqlDependancy to monitor this table. The query to track changes on this simple table can easily meet all requirements for `SqlDependancy`.